# How to use oracle SYSTIMESTAMP in prepared statement query?

Tags: java, prepared-statement, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need to run a insert query where one of the column has to store timestamp. This timestamp should be systemdate generated by oracle database while inserting. I am running a prepared Statement similar to this:

```
insert into table_name (column1 , timestamp) values(?,SYSTIMESTAMP);
```

But this is throwing exception in java while executing.

I have tried with this , it was working :

```
insert into table_name (column1 , timestamp) 
values(?,TO_TIMESTAMP(?, 'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM'));
```

Here I am passing timestamp generated by java , which is not my requirement. I have to store timestamp generated by DB.

Comment: please follow the code of conduct, and get to know how to post a question https://stackoverflow.com/conduct

Answer (score 0):

```
SQL> 
create table t (col1 number, col2 timestamp default systimestamp);

Table T created.


SQL> 
insert into t (col1) values (0);

1 row inserted.

SQL> 
insert into t (col1) values (1);

1 row inserted.

SQL> 
insert into t (col1, col2) values (2, systimestamp + 3);

1 row inserted.


SQL> 
select * from t;

      COL1 COL2                
---------- --------------------
         0 16-APR-2020 07.07.15
         1 16-APR-2020 07.07.15
         2 19-APR-2020 07.07.15
```

If you create the table column with default value, when inserting a row, oracle will insert the default value when a value is not provided.